# Google Sheets script to hide columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to scripts and am looking for some help. I have seen some other threads on this topic, but they are a bit over my head being a newby.

I need a script that would hide certain columns based on the content of a cell (BB5).

Example:
If BB5=3 Hide columns J-K, AJ-AM, AV, and BA.
If BB5=2 Hide columns H-K, AF-AM, AU-AV, and AZ-BA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## Hide columns based upon value in BB5

Example: If BB5=3 Hide columns J-K, AJ-AM, AV, and BA. If BB5=2 Hide columns H-K, AF-AM, AU-AV, and AZ-BA.

```
function hideMyColumns()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var vl=sh.getRange('BB5').getValue();
  var cols1=[10,11,36,37,38,39,48,53];
  var cols2=[8,9,10,11,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,47,48,52,53];
  switch(vl)
  {
    case 3:
      for(var i=0;i<cols1.length;i++)
      {
        sh.hideColumns(cols1[i]);
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      for(var i=0;i<cols2.length;i++)
      {
        sh.hideColumns(cols2[i]);
      }
  }

}
```

The Sheet Used to figure out column numbers

[image]

You can use this function for figuring out the column numbers.  Just select a cell on the correct row and color and this function will give you a string that you can copy into an array that you can use in the switch statement. I used the image provided above to get the column numbers needed.

```
function getColumns()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var color=ss.getActiveCell().getBackground();
  var row=ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var s='';
  var firstTime=true;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++)
    {
      if(i+1==row && vA[i][j]==color)
      {
        if(!firstTime){s+=',';}
        s+=Number(j+1);
        firstTime=false;
      }
    }
  }
  s+='<br />For color = ' + color + '<br />Row = ' + row;
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Column Numbers');
}
```